# Mapping theoretical transit options

Tags: maps, gtfs, transit

my area is building a new transit line, and I'd like to "add" it to trip planners for comparison's sake. Before I dive into Mapbox and reinvent the wheel, is there any way to add or reference a GTFS file from within an existing app, say, Google Transit, without adding it to the service?

Thanks for any help, and sorry if this is covered somewhere; I swear I didn't see it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do mean by `"add" it to trip planners`? What is `mapbox`?

Comment: My guess is that you want to add some new route/trip to existing schedule (available to you in GTFS file format) and simulate it, before submitting it to Google? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Import existing GTFS file into suitable editor. For example [this one](https://github.com/conveyal/gtfs-editor)
2. Add new "theoretical" transit line. Save it.
3. Export new data to new GTFS file
4. Use [schedule viewer](https://github.com/google/transitfeed/wiki/ScheduleViewer) to view it.

> Schedule Viewer is a Python program for viewing the contents of a GTFS feed on a map. It's a diagnostic program intended for those creating a feed

Source: https://github.com/google/transitfeed/wiki/ScheduleViewer

For more tools, see : https://developers.google.com/transit/tools